# How do you change the titles displayed inside infowindows in Carto?

Tags: carto

The titles in my infowindows are copied straight from my column headings in the underlying data... So it says "STREET_ADDRESS" when I'd like it to display "Address" or "YEAR" when I'd like it to display "Year registered"
Usually, Carto is point and click for these kinds of options, but I'm hitting a wall.

Answer (score 1):

There is toggle "HTML" in bottom part of the screen. This opens view, where you can edit more data, including title headings within `<h5 class="CDB-infowindow-subtitle">` element.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @JaakL response, you can also rename the column name with a custom value. As you said, it just (double) click and point!

[image: custom-popup]